# How to find tags without a description?

Tags: support

When I have time and there are no unanswered question I know an answer for, I would like to spend my time adding descriptions for tags that don't have a description yet.

I can browse trough all tags and check if they already have a description, but isn't there an easier way to find these tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh, no. I don't think so. Perhaps this question is more suited for [Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Yes maybe. Now as I think again about it, it is not really specific to Travel.